# How do I set width 100% in this html?

Tags: html, width

I how do I get this to display as the full width of the space? Width 100% isn't correct here. Thanks

```
<a style="background-color: #236b8e; font: Georgia; font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-    weight: bold; padding: 10px; width: 100%; text-decoration: none;" href="http://mysite.com/">Go There Now</a>
```

Comment: Can we see the context? The full HTML, possibly a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)...

Comment: Why are you using inline styles? Are you writing an HTML email?

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` is an [inline element](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) by default and therefore sizes to its contents. Add a `display: block` style to change it to block styling which will allow width sizing to work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `width` doesn't work on inline elements. If you make it a block element it can have a specifici width.

Add `display:block;` in the style to make it a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Please make your question clear. Is that text the only element in the webpage? if yes then add this to the CSS... Hope it helps.

EDIT: Well I guess this is what you are looking for..

```
   <a style="background-color: #236b8e; font: Georgia; font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-    weight: bold; 

padding: 10px;  display: block; text-decoration: none;" href="http://mysite.com/">Go There Now</a>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants 100% height.